# AWS EC2 - Change Security group - Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am trying out the tutorial for amazon VPC - Virtual private cloud.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html#Case2_Launch_NAT

I have followed these steps....

1. Navigate to https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc
2. Create a VPC.
3. Create security groups as outlined by the article.
4. I have created the NATSG security group as required by the article.
5. When I try to ***change the security group*** of the instance to run under the NATSG group it gives me an error - saying it encountered an error without any description.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're trying to do should work and without any error messages SO isn't going to be able to help you with this problem.  I'd recommend that you head over to the AWS support forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not facing the issue any longer - it appeared to be an ongoing issue at the time, I can currently switch security groups properly.

The one change I have made over the past 2 years is switch all my manual interactions with AWS to be programmatic using boto3 or cloudformation, which has eliminated a lot of errors.